# Apache Commons Http Client - Registering a client specific Protocol

Tags: java, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm working on a library that is meant to be integrated in other applications. I have to communicate with a https server, and I'm using apache commons HttpClient 3.1.  I have my own keystore and need to register a [Protocol](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/Protocol.html) via: `Protocol.registerProtocol`.  I was wondering if there was a way to register this for my specific instance of the client rather than statically - this way I don't mess up any other instances and nobody messes me up.

I saw something where I can get the clients HostConfiguration and call [setHost](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HostConfiguration.html#setHost%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol%29), with a protocol, but it doesn't appear to work properly.  I'm registering it like:

```
HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
config.setHost(remoteUrl.getHost(), remoteUrl.getPort(), new Protocol("https", new MyProtocolSocketFactory(), 443));
```

but when trying to make a connection, the SSL handshake fails, while it works when using Protocol.registerProtocol with the same parameters.  The failure is the standard:

`Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find valid certification path to requested target - error even after cert imported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Upgrade to HttpComponents 4 and leave client 3.x alone.