# Java connection to a https URL

Tags: java, url, ssl, https

I have written a small code in Java to access an URL .
The code works fine for HTTP connection, but fails for HTTPS  (the error is pasted below)

Any help to fix this will be greatly appreciated .

CODE :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class ConnectToWCProd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String userPassword = "user1:user1";
        String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode (userPassword.getBytes());

        //URL oracle = new URL("http://<URL>/");
        URL oracle = new URL("https://<URL>");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();

        yc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }

}
```

ERROR :

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
      at ConnectToWCProd.main(ConnectToWCProd.java:21)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
      at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
      at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
      ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
      at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
      ... 19 more

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find valid certification path to requested target - error even after cert imported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful to you:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210

Answer (score 1):

Read this [link](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html)

You have to include the certificate in `jre/lib/security/cacerts` (the default path)