# I get errors when i start libgdx gdx-setup-ui

Tags: java, libgdx

When I start `gdx-setup-ui` at the bottom bar, there pops 2 red balloon saying `Master config file 0/?? (?%)` and `Version number 0/??(?%)`. In the description of errors it says:

```
Ioexception sun.security.validator.validatorexception pkix path building failed:
sun.security.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certific
ation path to requested target
```

I get this error on my desktop PC, but i can use it without any problems on my laptop.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9210514/1007273 did you even bother searching??