# Spring boot with docker unable to find valid certification path to requested target error

Tags: spring, maven, docker, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot and am trying to set it up with ***Docker***. I've tried everything I could find on google and nothing seems to get me going. I'm running

```
 mvn clean package docker:build
```

Running this will do the spring-boot tests, run DB migrations, build the JAR, and then when it comes to Building the ***Docker image***, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.9:build (default-cli) 
on project app: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

Here is the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM java:8-jdk
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/james/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /tmp
ADD app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And here is my docker-maven-plugin configuration:

```
 ... pom stuff
<docker.image.prefix>jamesone1</docker.image.prefix>
    ... other pom stufff
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.9</version>
    <configuration>
            <dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
            <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
            <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>

            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                    <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                </resource>
            </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm using the dock for mac & am using a ***docker-machine*** with the following env:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/james/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
```

What's going on?! Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c

Answer (score 2):

fixed this in windows 10 by:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>yourImageName</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
                <dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Important are these two tags:

```
<dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
<dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
```

I am using a dockerfile, which path you have to define with this tag:

```
<dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
```

Now you can build your jar and generate docker image via:

mvn package docker:build

I think on mac just follwing value has to be different:

```
<dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
```

Comment: roak1997 you are welcome. Do you run it on Mac or Windows?

Comment: What's the dockerHost URL when using Docker For Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building the docker image by myself without the plugin:

```
docker build -f Dockefile .
```

And my Dockefile (has been renamed):

```
FROM java:8-jdk
EXPOSE 8080
#VOLUME /tmp

ADD target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/opt/demo/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I then run it like so:

```
 docker run <container id here>
```

I just couldn't get the mvn plugin to work!

#### Edit

Furthermore I ended up creating a `docker-compose.yml` which makes things a lot simpler!!!

You define properties such as the ports you want open, dockerfile location, and run docker-compose, and it'll magically build+run the docker image!

Example docker-compose.yml that I'm using:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
```

***build*** references the *Dockerfile* location. *Note you may need to the Dockerfile+yml file to be in the same location!

***ports*** reference the ports I want open. Now I can goto ***localhost:8080*** and my request will be forwarded to the docker container.

Read more on docker container here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/