# SpringBoot Docker unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, docker-toolbox, docker-maven-plugin

I am using DockerToolBox. I am trying to use Spring-Boot with Docker. I am following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/). pom.xml for my project is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jk-spring-boot-docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>jayram</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <!--dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost-->
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run this command : `mvn package docker:build`, I get following error :

```
Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default-cli) on project jk-spring-boot-docker: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
```

I tried adding `<dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>` in pom.xml, but I get following error :

```
Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default-cli) on project jk-spring-boot-docker: Exception caught: Timeout: GET https://192.168.99.100:2376/version: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 192.168.99.100:2376 [/192.168.99.100] failed: connect timed out
```

**UPDATE** :

Docker was not running. I started docker, and then I run the command, it gave following error :

```
Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default-cli) on project jk-spring-boot-docker: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: I assume you've internet access. Just pasting the error message in the Google search box and pressing enter sometimes can be very useful.

Comment: Thanks @AbhijitSarkar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240560/spring-boot-with-docker-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-tar/41622085#41622085 worked for me