# Tell java client code to accept self signed certificate

Tags: java, https, jvm

I want to connect to a `https` server which has a `self signed certificate`, without modifying my client code.

I know this question has been asked many times, but I couldn't get it to work. Here's what I've done:

1. Open the `https` server in Firefox
2. Click on the url info, then more info, then view certificate, then details, then click on export.
3. Choose the default export type setting (`X.509 Certificate (PEM)`, saved as `certificate.crt`), and save it to disk.
4. Open a command prompt, go to the `java_home` folder used by the client code, which in my case is `c:\jdk-7u55-windows-x64\jre\bin`
5. Enter the following command:

   ```
   keytool -import -v -trustcacerts
               -alias server-alias -file C:\Downloads\certificate.crt
               -keystore cacerts.jks -keypass changeit
               -storepass changeit
   ```

I also tried:

```
   keytool -import -v -trustcacerts
                    -alias server-alias2 -file C:\Downloads\certificate.crt
                    -keystore keystore.jks
```

6. **Restart** the client application

After all of this, I still get a `SSLHandshakeException` (unable to find valid certification path to requested target).
Full exception in log:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I don't know what I did wrong, what else to do or how to debug further.

Comment: can you verify the certificate has been imported properly to the trust store. use the following command to list certificates in trust store.
`keytool -list -keystore cacerts.jks`

also please append the logs related to failure.

Comment: @dammina yes, the list command shows server-alias as being imported today. And the logs just show that SSLHandshakeException. I have added the full exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c

Answer (score 0):

Specifying absolute path to needed `cacerts.jks` should help. Current use of `keytool` just creates new .jks to your current directory which (i suppose) is `c:\jdk-7u55-windows-x64\jre\bin`. Default cacerts location is usualy at `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`. Alternatively you can use 
`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to custom store> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<custom store_passwd>` as starting arguments of your app. [More info](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/adminguide/cadminsslkeys.html)