# Can't setup dagger, prefix for component fails

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to learn Dagger. But when I try to create a new object through a component with a Dagger prefix, it tells me "cannot resolve symbol". Searching online, apparently I'm supposed to include something like this:

```
dependencies {

    compile files('libs/dagger-2.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-compiler-2.8.jar')
    ...

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8' code generation
}
```

But this is the error I get:

> Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested
>   target

It seems to recognize the apt command but not 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'. Anyone know how to solve this..?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a proxy issue. Try connecting through a wifi that is not behind a proxy and then building

Comment: @DavidRawson Looks like you're right, it is a proxy issue. Do you know if there's a way to do it offline though? It seems like it just wants jars that I have already included in the project...

Comment: you can try downloading the jars from [maven central](https://search.maven.org/) and put them in your `libs` folder. Also consider setting up a wifi hotspot on your phone (if it has 3G/4G), connecting your computer, then building

Comment: Dagger compiler should not be a compile time dependency

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How should I include the Dagger compiler jar?

Comment: Have you tried `apt` instead of compile?

Comment: I tried:
apt files('libs/dagger-compiler-2.8.jar')
...But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with Gradle, not with Dagger. When you add the dependency on Dagger-2 to the `build.gradle` and build, Gradle will attempt to download the new dependencies for your project.

Hence the error you are getting when Gradle attempts to download Dagger 2:

> The valid certification path to requested target

This seems to be caused by workplace proxies if they 'man-in-the-middle' with their own self-signed SSL certificates. You can try exporting the certificates from your workplace into the Java environment following the instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html) and if that doesn't work, there are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c).

If that fails, perhaps you can download the jars from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.dagger%22%20AND%20a%3A%22dagger-compiler%22) or simply run the build while connected to a network that is not behind a hostile proxy.

Comment: You could  download the annotation processor and put it in your libs like the dagger dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

See the dagger docs here: https://github.com/google/dagger

Gradle should be like so:

```
// Add Dagger dependencies
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and looked at the dagger docs, but I still get the same error. Any other suggestions..?

Comment: @Harambe The above should work if you have Gradle 2.2.2 - Check the project build.gradle file

Comment: Maybe switch annotationprocessor with apt