# How to deploy my code to App Engine behind proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, ssl, proxy

I am using Eclipse Neon 6.4.3 and i am trying to deploy my project to App Engine using the Google Cloud Platform plugin for Eclipse. https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart

Until the 1st of April i could deploy projects using this plugin. But after that date, i get the following error:

> Failed to retrieve projects; An error occurred while retrieving projects:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuiderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
>
> Reason:  Failed to retrieve projects.
>
> Details:  Failed to retrieve projects
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

After I press OK, I get the same message again. Then I get the "Deploy to App Engine Standard" menu with my account but my project list is blank.

I am working in a company that uses proxies and it's doing a SSL Inspection. I imported these 2 certificates used for SSL Inspection in my Eclipse cacerts file but i get the same error. These two certificates are issued by our internal certificate authority.

Comment: Can you check if any of these helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c

Comment: I already tried the solution in the first post. Didn't work. I tried the solution in the second post, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but still don't have enough points:

Are you using maven or appcfg? Have you tried using appcfg with `--proxy` argument?

From [Deploying a Java app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/uploadinganapp#using_appcfg_alternative) documentation:

> If you are using an HTTP proxy, include the `--proxy` argument to tell appcfg its address. If you use a different proxy for HTTPS, then also include the `--proxy_https` argument.

Comment: The current version (and the one that was released at the time of Aprli 1st) of the Cloud Tools for Eclipse supports Eclipse's proxy settings. I wonder if this may be a change on the company network itself? The fact that the issue started to happen on the first day of the month may suggest it.

Comment: I asked my security and network departments and they didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The current certificate for the URL used to retrieve the projects `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/` was issued on April 5 2017, this may be the reason for the error. If you open that url and check the certificate you can verify whether it's signing CA is in the truststore you use, or you need to add either the CA or the certificate itself to your truststore.

Comment: Hi, i imported that certificate also. Still the same issue. The problem is that when i view the certificate is not issued by google, but by my company. :(