# Issue while generating release version of signed apk Android gradle 3.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[image: Please find below the screen shot for the issue]
 any help is deeply appreciated in advance.

When i change gradle version to 3.0.1 then it works fine for both Debug and release version of signed apk but when i keep it 3.1.1.. it gives me the same issue..

Comment: where is screen shot

Comment: Where is the screenshot?@Amit

Comment: Thanks for your reply... please refresh :)

Comment: Check this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c @Amit

Comment: When i change gradle version to 3.0.1 then it works fine but it doesnt work with 3.1.1 , that too only for release signed apk but when i go for debug signed apk it works fine..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- At First **UPGRADE** version & **Update** Your Android Studio.
- Check your **PROXY**

At First

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
```

**Read Your Error Log**

You should call  **`implementation`** instead of **`compile`**.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:****" // use api
```

Then

```
 lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                abortOnError false
            }
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart IDE`**.

Comment: When i change gradle version to 3.0.1 then it works fine but it doesnt work with 3.1.1 , that too only for release signed apk but when i go for debug signed apk it works fine..

Comment: @Amit okay. Same problem for `gradle:3.1.2` ?

Comment: @Amit you should use `implementation` for good approach.

Comment: yes i'm using implementation , when using 3.1.2 it says

Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2.

which it is trying to find at location - 

/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom

below is the url it is trying to download from

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom

when i open this link in the browser it gives me 404.

i have also trying url shared by dhanshri (She commented in the question )

Comment: @Amit add `lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }`

Comment: sorry i missed to mention i have used lintOptions also and facing same issue.
of lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom

Comment: @Amit  add `implementation group: 'com.android.tools.lint', name: 'lint-gradle', version: '26.1.1'`

Comment: when i say lintOptions {  checkReleaseBuilds false }
it works,

please help me to understand what issue i may face if i set it to false...

Comment: implementation group: 'com.android.tools.lint', name: 'lint-gradle', version: '26.1.1'

doesn't work it says cant resolve it ...do not know why so.. :(

Comment: @Amit   Bro. Your thought saved me. changed gradle version from 3.1.2 to 3.0.1. ..  Got Release build.   Tq

Comment: @KartiikeyaBaleneni Okay. Happy to hear.

Comment: i am not allowed to ask another questions due to some reasons may be...

@IntelliJ Amiya need your help,

i have installed studio 3.2 canary 16 wanted to use JetPack features (android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel)

gradle version 3.2.0,

it gives me Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


for older version of studio no issues everything works fine...

Please help :)

Comment: @Amit `installed studio 3.2 canary 16 ` whenever trying to make RELEASE apk use STABLE version.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention...That the issue comes while building gradle...that means i am not able to run project on my device also or in emulator also...

trying to sync gradle but it gives the same issue,

if you have time can we chat sometimes :)