# Facing issues adding certain valid maven dependencies to maven's pom.xml using intellij idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, dropwizard

I did n't faced any issues adding dropwizard-core, dropwizard-client to my pom.xml. But later to implement authentication and testing i tried to add dropwizard-auth and dropwizard-test maven dependencies to my pom.xml but unfortunately application is not picking up and i see them highlighted in red , eventhough pom.xml does n't show any error.

Below is my dependency list

App
  https://mvnrepository.com

```
<properties>
    <dropwizard.version>1.0.0</dropwizard.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <docker.registry.name></docker.registry.name><!-- leave empty for docker hub; use e.g. "localhost:5000/" for a local docker registry -->
    <docker.repository.name>${docker.registry.name}phauer/${project.artifactId}</docker.repository.name>
    <hbase.version>1.4.6</hbase.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.serviceenabled</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-request-tracker</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

There is no error being shown on my pom.xml but my Dependencies tab is underlined in red color for those dependencies. Attached image shows how it looks[image]

I'm unable to find a fix why this is happening. It's happening only for specific maven dependencies. Please advice me regarding the same.

Maven compilation is throwing below error:

> Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/dropwizard/dropwizard-testing/0.9.1/dropwizard-testing-0.9.1.pom
>
> Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/maven-metadata.xml
>
> [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project App Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.app:App:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to
>   collect dependencies at io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:jar:0.9.1:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:jar:0.9.1: Could not transfer
>   artifact io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:pom:0.9.1 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Please help me how to fix this issue

Comment: Is that image the most up to date with all the dependencies you currently have in your pom? It doesn't look like it matches up.

Comment: The `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` should be about the `truststore` that it is not able to find the root certificate chain. Basically the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 uses the commercial certificate which should be available at the `JDK cacerts`. Could you please show the `mvn -v`? It may be an issue about your JDK version. Please visit the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514 for further information.

Comment: JDK version setup is wrong based on the message. furthermore do not use `RELEASE` as a version...

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable comments. I was able to fix this issue changing the dropwizard version from 1.0 to 1.3.4 as suggested by @PaulSamsotha