# Can't receive mail from POP3 GMAIL by using Javamail, get SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, gmail, ssl-certificate, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have JAVA application which work as service on Tomcat server. I need to develope service for receiving mail from GMAIL pop3 server. I use Javamail. I have written usual code, but when I deploy it on server I am getting

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

As for development my Tomcat started on Localhost.
And this problemm looks like concerned with certificate.

My code is

```
    public void downloadMail() {
        try {
            // connects to the message store and opens the inbox folder
            Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
            store.connect(username, password);
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder(inbox);
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            // fetches new messages from server
            Message[] messages = folderInbox.getMessages();

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Mail mail = extractMail(messages[i]);
                messages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
            }

            // disconnect
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
             System.out.println( "No provider for pop3.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
             System.out.println( "Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             System.out.println( "Can not save file or open directory");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting exception on line **store.connect(username, password);**

I use properties:

```
mail.pop3.host=pop.gmail.com
mail.pop3.port=995
mail.pop3.ssl.enable=true
mail.pop3.protocol=pop3
mail.pop3.inbox=INBOX
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I never worked with Tomcat and certificates before!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find valid certification path to requested target - error even after cert imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c)

Comment: See this [JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#installcert).