# Can I use the old cert if I upgraded JDK 1.6 to JDK 1.7?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-7, java-6

I upgraded JDK 1.6 to 1.7 then install cert to new version (1.7).
I mean install in cacerts not in keystore.

But I found this exception "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

For more, Exception between connection server to server and it happened after upgrade JDK to 1.7 but I added the cert same with JDK 1.6 .

I need to know if I upgrade JDK version then I should be create new cert or can use the old cert ?

Comment: Have you followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean follow the correct post ?

Comment: I mean please have a look at the accepted answer on that question and see if that helps you determine what the problem is. "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" often means that the cert is not valid, e.g. self-signed and/or expired.

Comment: I think not same case because the old version work fine but after I upgrade version and import the same cert into the new version it's not working. I need to know I should be owner destination server to gen the new cert or can use the old cert because I used the old cert but not working

Comment: Have you tried generating a new certificate? If that works, wouldn't that solve your problem?