# unable to find valid certification path to requested target exception even after adding required certificates

Tags: java, webservice-client

Even after doing the below steps, I am unable to establish a connection to https link

1. Converted .crt and .key file to .p12 through openssl
2. Converted .p12 file to .jks file through keytool (though I could directly mention .p12 in the code)
3. Added generated .jks file to cacerts present in jdk/jre/lib/security
4. My client code is here

> ```
> KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
> trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("test.jks"), "changeit".toCharArray());
> TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
> tmf.init(trustStore);
> TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();
> System.out.println(tms.length);
> //this is gives me 1
> SSLContext sslContext = null;
> sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
> sslContext.init(null, tms, new SecureRandom());
> HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
> URL url;
> url = new URL(" https://testurl.com");
> HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
> urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
> urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
> urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
> urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
> urlConn.setDoInput(true);
> urlConn.connect();
> ```

5. Tried adding truststore in System property as well but same error.
6. Tried adding truststore/keystore in VM arguments, still got the same error.

What else should I try to make it work?

Comment: There is some debugging/troubleshooting guidance in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c). Have you tried any of those options?

Comment: I tried adding -Djavax.net.debug=SSL in VM arguments and I see this error at the end of the console - ***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: the code works for me if the keystore test.jks contains a valid CA for the certificate of the target url. can you list the certificates in test.jks?

Comment: I had got .crt and .key file from the server. Then I converted these to .jks file. I believe it should contain valid certificate. I tried sending request through postman with .crt and .key file and I was able to successfully receive the response

Comment: is ssl certificate verification turned on in your postman settings?

Comment: yes. otherwise I would have not got response :)

Comment: kindly help on above mentioned issue!

Comment: I tried same code in Mac system it executed beautifully! why same java code and certificate is not working in Windows 10 machine :(