# Jenkins with Azure AD integration fails with "A problem occurred while processing the request"

Tags: jenkins, azure-active-directory, ssl-certificate, truststore

There is lot of help available. Not able to fix it. After I enter my user name and password.
Jenkins with Azure AD login is successful and it return the token also. After that it fails with **"A problem occurred while processing the request"**. Login is successful when I see the Azure side and jenkins ui prints token also.

```
When I see the error logs, I see 
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|Handling POST /securityRealm/finishLogin from x.x.x.x : Jetty (winstone)-19|2021-07-15 19:36:53.374 EDT|Utilities.java:73|the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=login.microsoftonline.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=login.microsoftonline.com)
2021-07-15 23:36:55.398+0000 [id=326]   INFO    c.m.a.a.AuthenticationAuthority#doInstanceDiscovery: [Correlation ID: e11160be-50c3-43d7-96a8-dc02c3cc2b2c] Instance discovery was successful
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|13|Handling POST /securityRealm/finishLogin from x.x.x.x : Jetty (winstone)-19|2021-07-15 19:36:55.769 EDT|TransportContext.java:344|Fatal **** (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {
```

Also

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|Handling POST /securityRealm/finishLogin from x.x.x.x : Jetty (winstone)-19|2021-07-15 19:36:55.773 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1569|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|Handling POST /securityRealm/finishLogin from x.x.x.x : Jetty (winstone)-19|2021-07-15 19:36:55.773 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1588|close the SSL connection (initiative)
2021-07-15 23:36:55.787+0000 [id=19]    SEVERE  c.m.j.azuread.AzureSecurityRealm#doFinishLogin: error
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have imported certs for login.microsoftonline.com and portal.azure.com, my jenkins.xml has

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\.cacerts\jssecacerts"  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Not sure what website it says "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Comment: So you have followed a guide like this one https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-ad/ for integrating your login into Jenkins throughout Azure AD?

Comment: Yes, we followed those steps

Answer (score 0):

As posted in another entry in stack overflow I'd try to debug what is happening with your trustStore with something like:

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\.cacerts\jssecacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

You may want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw lot of debugs with this. I see this ``` javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|02 76|Handling POST /securityRealm/finishLogin from x.x.x.x : Jetty (winstone)-630|2021-07-19 13:36:35.524 EDT|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:73|WRITE: TLS12 alert(certificate_unknown), length = 2.  ``` Does this mean Azure is not able to POST to my jenkins on prem due to certs? my jenkins on prem has digi certs.

Comment: ** Can someone confirm if Jenkins is onprem, does Azure AD plugin works? **

Comment: As everyone's case is different. I had to import symmantec certs our company uses. Java was not trusting this. Now its working. Moral This is a good link everyone knows already stackoverflow.com/questions/24563694/… Also enable SSL login with -Djavax.net.debug=all in jenkins.xml for further debugging.