# Not able to bypass javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

Tags: spring-boot, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, spring-cloud-gateway

---

- **I do understand it is not a best practice to bypass SSL certification
  but for my local testing I need that. So I have two secured(https)
  localhost and I want to access the second localhost from the first
  one using spring gateway**

---

- For generating SSL certificate I have used this link
  https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-example/

To bypass SSL check I have added this piece of the code in the main class for both gateway and consumer

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error" + e);
        }

        SpringApplication.run(Gateway.class, args);
    }
```

Yet I am still getting this handshake exception. What I am missing?

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:477) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) [netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) [netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_301]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/consumer" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a hack in spring boot gateway to achieve this

spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.ssl.use-insecure-trust-manager=true

Answer (score 0):

You could check who is calling hostname verifier (via catching Exception with a breakpoint).. your stack might be not exactly the same as in tutorial someone wrote 1 year ago.

In my case I had to add

```
@Bean
    public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
      TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer = new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
      tlsProtocolConfigurer.setSslHostnameVerification("allowAll");
      return tlsProtocolConfigurer;
    }
```

Have you checked that thread?
[Unable to find valid certification path to requested target - error even after cert imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c)

Comment: For the time being I was hoping to bypass all the certification validation over https

Comment: Understood, but if you are using spring stack you need to do it in a spring way, calling some functions in main() is not enough.