# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c

when I am running email option from Markview application then I am getting this error

`unable to find valid certification path to requested target (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`

Recently we have configured SSL on web logic. Unable to get the issue .

Comment: this may be many things, one of the most common is by handshaking with a self-certificate that root CA certificate is not un truststore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c

Comment: Yeah got it figured out as it was a jdk issue which has to be updated in database