# Spring Boot - Unable to find valid certification path to requested target error even after adding the cerficates to keystore

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, httpsurlconnection

I am developing a REST API using Spring Boot and trying to connect to an SSO(https) on my network. Everything worked fine until the ssl cerificate on the SSO was recently updated. Now I keep getting the following error.

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

I have looked at other answers [ans 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c), [ans 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ) for the same problem and I have tried to add all the cerificates in the chain to keystore and it is still giving me the same exception. I have restarted the pc several times now.

When I check the keystore using list command I can see my ceritficates are present in the list but it still doesnt work.

So what am I doing wrong?

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.3 on Intellij IDEA 2020.2 and everything worked fine, even the SSO was validating the tokens but recently the SSO's ssl certifcate was updated. It is a self-signed certificate from Lets Encrypt. But I am not sure how that could be a problem since the previous certificate was also from Lets Encrypt.

Comment: Let's encrypt's root CA expired last week.

Comment: What about the browser? Does it recognize the endpoint as having valid certificate? Make sure it is not expired or something.

Comment: Yes the browser recognize it just fine. Its java that doesnt recognize it

Comment: You can try letting java print the keystore it is using. maybe it is using a different keystore. (that was one problem I had in the past...)

Comment: @StephanStahlmann I did using -Djavax.net.debug=all. And the SSO certificate is in there along with other certs in the  chain